# pandas & split() makes the blank row in excel

Tags: python, pandas

I made columns string as below

```
columns = ['a b c d e'.split(' ')]
```

This is for my convenient instead 'a', 'b', .........

then, set the df as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(top, columns=columns)
```

finally, I sent it to excel. There it is.

```
    a     b       c           d       e
                    
0   전세  109/84  100,000     204동    고/29
1   월세  61/39   45,000/90   308동    고/21
2   월세  110/84  70,000/120  412동    고/29
3   월세  110/84  2,000/240   203동    저/29
4   전세  140/110 180,000     313동    고/35
```

As you can see, there is blank 2nd row in sheet.

When I tried it just with

```
#columns = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

there was not shown any blank row.

Could you let me get it?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you pass nested lists, so get `MultiIndex` with one level, for avoid it use:

```
top = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4]
})

columns = 'a b c d e'.split()

#assign new colums names
top.columns = columns
print (top)
   a  b  c  d  e
0  a  4  7  1  5
1  b  5  8  3  3
2  c  4  9  5  6
3  d  5  4  7  9
4  e  5  2  1  2
5  f  4  3  0  4
```